# Cite_key instead of a number, what is going on?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have the following problem: I correctly obtain a numbered bibliography at the end but along the text the cite_key appear instead of a number. How to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
%some text 
... \cite{ABKM2015}...
%some text 
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ABKM2015}
Arroja, F. and Bartolo, N. and Karmakar P. and Matarrese, S. (2015).
\newblock The Two Faces of Mimetic Horndeski Gravity            
\newblock {\em ArXiV}, 1506.08575 (2015).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

After compiling I get
... [**ABKM2015**] ...
while I want for example  [1].

Comment: You seem to be mixing 'classical' bibliography generation (hard-coded `\bibitem` data) with `biblatex`: that won't work. Can you detail a little more what you hope to achieve?

Comment: See also [Problem with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275015/35864). `biblatex` does not work with the manual `thebibliography`. You will have to start using `biblatex` properly, see my comments on your other question for starters.

Comment: I don't want to use biblatex but instead to use the embedded thebibliography environment. How to get numbers instead of the cite_key? It seems an easy request to me..

Comment: If you don't want to use `biblatex` why do you load it then?

Comment: Because if I don't load it, I get an error and compilation won't proceed

Comment: No, `\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
... \cite{ABKM2015}...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ABKM2015}
Arroja, F. and Bartolo, N. and Karmakar P. and Matarrese, S. (2015).
\newblock The Two Faces of Mimetic Horndeski Gravity            
\newblock {\em ArXiV}, 1506.08575 (2015).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}` does not give an error at all and gives you what you want.

Comment: Here it doesn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31371/discussion-between-moewe-and-yngabl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `biblatex` together with a manual `thebibliography` environment. While BibTeX is compatible with `thebibliography`, `biblatex` completely re-implements all citation and bibliography commands and cannot be used with classical BibTeX nor with the manual `thebibliography`.

---

If you want to use `thebibliography` you need to get rid of `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\ifundef\doi
  {\DeclareUrlCommand\doi{}}
  {}
\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{ABKM2015} ipsum.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ABKM2015}
Arroja, F. and Bartolo, N. and Karmakar P. and Matarrese, S. (2015).
\newblock The two faces of mimetic Horndeski gravity:
  disformal transformations and Lagrange multiplier
\newblock \emph{Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics}
 15/09 (2015), 051
\newblock DOI: \doi{10.1088/1475-7516/2015/09/051}
\newblock arXiv:\texttt{1506.08575 [gr-qc]}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

works just fine.

[image: Arroja, F. and Bartolo, N. and Karmakar P. and Matarrese, S. (2015). The two faces of mimetic Horndeski gravity: disformal transformations and Lagrange multiplier Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics 15/09 (2015), 051 DOI: 10.1088/1475-7516/2015/09/051 arXiv:1506.08575 [gr-qc]]

---

Conversely, if you want to use `biblatex` you can't have `thebibliography` and must instead provide the data for your entries in a `.bib` file.

`mybibfile.bib` would contain

```
@article{ABKM2015,
  author      = {Frederico Arroja and Nicola Bartolo
                 and Purnendu Karmakar and Sabino Matarrese},
  title       = {The two faces of mimetic {Horndeski} gravity:
                 disformal transformations and {Lagrange} multiplier},
  journal     = {Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics},
  volume      = {2015},
  number      = {9},
  eid         = {051},
  doi         = {10.1088/1475-7516/2015/09/051},
  date        = {2015-09},
  eprinttype  = {arxiv},
  eprint      = {1506.08575},
  eprintclass = {gr-qc},
}
```

and would be used as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, maxbibnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{ABKM2015} ipsum.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Frederico Arroja, Nicola Bartolo, Purnendu Karmakar and Sabino Matarrese. ‘The two faces of mimetic Horndeski gravity: disformal transformations and Lagrange multiplier’. In: Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics 2015.9, 051 (Sept. 2015). doi: 10.1088/1475-7516/2015/09/051. arXiv: 1506.08575 [gr-qc].]

---

It is a good idea to delete all temporary auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) after changes to the bibliography set-up to make sure that there are no errors due to now undefined or redefined macro calls in the auxiliary files.

Answer (score 0):

When you are putting your bibliography manually with bibitem, just change `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` to `\usepackage{cite}` and your citation will appear in number.