# Bibliography not showing reference numbers

Tags: bibliographies

I am wrapping up my thesis (deadline is very close) and I just can't get the bibliography working. I use the package, and make everything according to the manual but I cant get the reference number to show up, instead I get the reference name. 
Basically I have three issues:

1. I would like to have a reference number at the citation, not the citation reference
2. Instead of References chapter name I would like to have the Hungarian name which is Referenciák
3. I would like the reference section to show up in the contents section

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % report

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <============================================
\usepackage{mathptmx} % ez a times new roman

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %ez az oldalszamozast csinalja

\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %
%\usepackage{graphicx} % <=========================================
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext} % kamuszoveget ad
%\usepackage{mwe} %kepek egymas mellett

\usepackage{geometry} % ez a margin beallitasokat
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{ragged2e} %justification left/right
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\usepackage{biblatex} %referenciak
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %referenciak

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath <================================
\usepackage[ceqn]{nccmath}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{soul} %sorkiemelő
\usepackage{xcolor} %sorkiemelő

\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} %todo buborekok
%\usepackage{todonotes} %todo buborekok 
\usepackage{verbatim} %a kikommenteleshez
\usepackage{epigraph} %idezet az elso oldalon

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % ez csinal linket a contentsbol <================

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % <=======================================

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge}{\large}{\center}{}% for \chapter*
\makeatother

\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{comment}
\fancypagestyle{elso_old}
\fancyfoot{
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3cm}} l@{\hspace{2.8cm}}                                                                 l@{\hspace{3cm}}}
\textbf{OE-BGK} &  Hallgató neve: & Zsarnowszky Lóránt \\
\textbf{2017} &  Hallgató törzsszáma: & T004562/FI12904/B \\
\end{tabular}
}
}
\end{comment}






%\fancyfoot[L]{OE-BGK \\ 2017.}
%\fancyfoot[C]{Hallgató neve: \\ Hallgató törzskönyvi száma:}




\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Ábra}

\geometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=20mm, top=40mm, bottom=40mm}

\title{Szakdolgozat}
\date{}
\author{Zsarnowszky Loránt}




















\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{roman} % <===============================================

%\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{BMElogo.png}
%\caption{}
\end{figure}


\vspace*{8\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
A mobil robotok navigációja
\end{LARGE}  
\end{center}
%


\vspace*{12\baselineskip}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3cm}} l@{\hspace{2.4cm}}                                                                 l@{\hspace{3cm}}}
\textbf{OE-BGK} &  Hallgató neve: & \textbf{XXX} \\
\textbf{2017} &  Hallgató törzsszáma: & \textbf{XXX} \\
\end{tabular}
}

\thispagestyle{empty}



%<===============================================


\newpage



\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
%\justify
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Bevezetés}
%ez itt egy komment

%\epigraph{Bip bip bee bee bip}{\textit{R2-D2}}


Alapvetően három különböző robot típust különböztetünk meg: a vezérelt robotot, az automatizált robotot és az autonóm azaz önálló robotot.\\ 
A vezérelt robotok esetében mindenképp szükség van emberi üzemeltetésre. Ezek jellemzően olyan robotok melyek teljes mértékben függnek az emberi irányítástól, önállóan semmilyen feladatot, tevékenységet nem végeznek. Vezérelt robotokat gyakran alkalmaznak orvosi műtétek során illetve katonai akciók, bombák hatástalanítása alkalmából.

Az automatizált robotok eklatáns példái az ipari robotok. Ezek olyan robotok melyek egy előre beprogramozott műveletsort végeznek el egy ellenőrzött környezetben ismétlődő ciklusokban. Ilyen robotokat gyakran láthatunk gépjármű-összeszerelő üzemekben vagy akár az általunk összerakott és leprogramozott Lego Mindstorm robot is ezen robotcsoportba sorolható.

Az előző két típussal ellentétben az autonóm  (vagy önálló) robotok képesek egy - akár - számukra ismeretlen környezetben saját döntéseket hozni a megadott cél elérése érdekében. Egyre több ilyen robottal találkozhatunk a jelenkorban: az önjáró fűnyíróktól, az önvezető autókon keresztül egészen a csomagszállító drónokig. Napjaink egyik legnagyobb kihívása, hogy minél több - ember által elvégzett - feladatot átadhassunk a robotoknak, úgy, hogy a szükséges emberi beavatkozást minimálisra csökkentsük.


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{kiva_robot.png}
\caption{\label{fig:kiva robot}Az Amazon által alkalmazott Kiva robot.\cite{kivarobot}}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\end{wrapfigure}
\todo{hivatkozást betenni a képbe}

Az autonóm robotok lehetőséget adnak arra, hogy óriási mértében növeljük a termelés minőségét és hatékonyságát. Csak, hogy megemlítsek egy pár ilyen területet a teljesség igénye nélkül: csomagszállítás, logisztika, takarítás, mezőgazdaság, földművelés.
Ahhoz, hogy egy nap majd ezen tevékenységeket robotok végezhessék nagyon fontos, hogy balesetmentesen és megbízhatóan tudjanak közlekedni számukra ismeretlen, még fel nem térképezett területeken is. 

\subsection{A szakdolgozat tartalmi összefoglalója}

A szakdolgozatom első részében a mobil robot megvalósításának elméleti hátteréről értekezek. Sorra veszem a robot irányításáért felelős vezérlést és a vezérlési típusokat, a belső- illetve külső információk rögzítéséért felelős érzékelőket, a robot meghajtását és a különböző útkeresési algoritmusokat és viselkedés formákat. A szakdolgozat második részében már a gyakori megvalósításáról írok, a harmadik részben pedig kifejtem az elméleti rész és a gyakorlati megvalósítás során tapasztalt egyezőségeket és különbségeket.




\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{kivarobot}
www.fastcompany.com: Your Amazon Order Might Now Be Filled By A Robot\\
Photo via Kiva Robots: \texttt{https://www.fastcompany.com/3038873/your-amazon-order-might-now-be-filled-by-a-robot}
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

This is the problem no 1 I am having:

[image]

Comment: Haven't tested the code yet, you why at you loading biblatex when the bibliography you are showing is made by hand and clearly not by biblatex. Also you probably want to format urls with the url package, not `\texttt`

Comment: As assumed, the behaviour you see is due to loading `biblatex` but using a manual bibliography. Decide on which one you want to use, you probably cannot use both.

Comment: Thank daleif very much for your comment! I have deleted the package, but now I get ?? instead of the number.
The only change is that the reference section is in hungarian.
However it does not show up in the contents section and I get [??] instead of [1].

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: Did you compile several times? I usually compile using `latexmk -pdf`, which compiles the doc several times if needed.

Comment: When I remove both lines `\usepackage{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`,  typesetting your code gives `[1]` in the caption (I also have to change `hungarian` to `english` in the `babel` option, it doesn't typeset with `hungarian`).  I would personally recommend putting all references in a separate file, rather than in the same `.tex` document.

Comment: Have a look at [LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864)

Comment: Hi Everyone! Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!
I have only one question left now. 
I still cant see the reference chapter in the table of contents! And I also would like it to be numbered as a section. How can I do that?
Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Just so we don't get lost in the comments:

1. To fix the caption problem, don't load `biblatex`. That is, comment out the following two lines in the header.

   ```
   \usepackage{biblatex} %referenciak
   \addbibresource{sample.bib} %referenciak
   ```
2. To change the title of the References section in the text, put the following code right after you load the `babel` package.

   ```
   \addto\captionshungarian{
     \renewcommand\refname{Referenciák}
   }
   ```
3. To see the References in the Table of Contents with your custom name, in the text just before `\begin{thebibliography}`, put the following code.

   ```
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referenciák}
   ```

Comment: Isn't Hungarian supported by latex? Asking babel to run with option English will typeset the text with English hyphernation patterns which is clearly wrong

Comment: @daleif you're right - the `hungarian` option wasn't typesetting for me at first. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142358/19372) told me to `sudo apt install texlive-lang-european`, then delete the `.aux` file, then typeset. I adjusted my answer with `\captionshungarian`, which now typesets for me with the desired result.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I use upsteam TeXLive instead of the Ubuntu\debian one, then I have everything by default.