# Can Anyone Explain to me the error in my use of BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Progress Through Paradox}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
 mechanical development came, in equal measure, responses seeking to disprove 
them, as was the formulation of the 'EPR Paradox' in response to Heisenberg and 
Bohr's 'Copenhagen Interpretation' understanding of quantum mechanical variables 
(in particular their uncertainties)\cite{Copenhagen Interpretation}, 

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{Quantum Paradoxes}
Aharonov Y, Rohrlich D.
\textit{Quantum Theory for the Perplexed}
Quantum Paradoxes. 2005; 25-3, 46-51, 61-69.
\bibitem{Copenhagen Interpretation}
Heisenberg W.
 \textit{Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematik und 
Mechanik [The content of the quantum theoretical kinematics and mechanics]}.
 Z. Phys. 1927; 43: 172–198.
\bibitem{EPR}
Einstein A, Podolsky B, Rosen N. 
\textit{Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered 
Complete?}.
Description of Physical Reality. 1935; 47: 777-780.
\bibitem{Bell's Inequality}
Bell J.
\textit{ON THE EINSTEIN PODOLSKY ROSEN PARADOX}.
Physics. 1964; 1[I]: 195-200.
\bibitem{Bohm's Spin Discussion}
Bohm D, Aharonov Y.
\textit{Discussion of Experimental Proof for the Paradox of Einstein, Rosen, and 
Podolsky}.
PHYSICAL REVIEW. 1957; 108-4: 1070-1076.
\bibitem{Spin-Bell's Theorem}
Mathpages: Quantum Entanglement and Bell's Theorem
\newline
http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath521/kmath521.htm
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

The citation of 'Copenhagen Interpretation' does not appear correctly, I know this can be a complicated issue but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now to no avail.

Comment: You should probably use a `.bib` file instead of manual bibliography management. At least that's the purpose of biblatex.

Comment: The first mistake you make is that you try to write the `thebibliography`-environment by hand. If you want to use biblatex, put the works you want to cite in a .bib-file and let biblatex and bibtex or biber sort and produce your bibliography.

Comment: How do I create a .bib file?

Comment: A `.bib` file can be created with a text editor of your chioce. This file contains the information that `biblatex` and `biber` need to sort and cormat your bibliography. In oder to function correctly, the individual entries must be formatted according to some rules. You can find an example here: \end{filecontents} (the part between `\begin{filecontents}` and `\end{filecontents}` is an example entry for a book)

Comment: You can't use the manual approach of writing a bibliography with `thebibliography` and `biblatex` at the same time. Choose only one of the two approaches. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864

Answer (score 0):

`\bibitem` defines the ID of the bibliography entry in `biblatex` and as far as I know no spaces are allowed there.
To avoid syntax errors and to be able to manage all your references in a convenient way you should use a `bibtex` editor. It will provide you with a database containing your references (the `.bib` file) in the correct format. This is the file that you can easily refer to in your `LaTeX` documents. And in most cases the editor comes with a handy user interface to add and sort your references as well as with an error checking system. One example for those editors is the platform independent *JabRef*.