# \cite does not refer to items of thebibliography environment

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am using the `thebibliography`-environment to produce a bibliography for my Latex-file. Iniating the bibliography this way works perfectly fine.

My problem is that I can use any argument for the `\cite`-command, and it will just be presented in the output in the following manner:

`\cite{lalala}`:
[image: lalala-citation]

`\cite`does not refer to the items of `\thebibliography`-environment.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{Vortrag(2)}
\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{=\vcentcolon}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto,array}
\usepackage{dsfont,lipsum}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
```

This is the (I think) relevant part of the Vortrag(2).cls-file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Vortrag}[2014/11/03 besides page geometry fully set up scrreprt class]

\LoadClass[fontsize=12pt, ngerman, twoside=true, twocolumn=false, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}   
\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitB,bookmarks=false, urlcolor=3, linkcolor=5]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=5,
    linktoc=page, %Optinen: page - name - all
}

\RequirePackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, inner=2cm, outer=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}                             

\clubpenalty 10000
\widowpenalty 10000

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\color{3}\bfseries}
\setcapindent{1em}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading, figuresignature} 
\RequirePackage{dsfont, mathtools, amssymb, delarray, graphicx, nicefrac,mathrsfs}

\RequirePackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage[amsmath, thmmarks, hyperref]{ntheorem}
\makeatother
```

I got the cls-file from a friend and I don't know the meaning of every command.

My aim is to use `\cite`, such that it produces just a number of cited article/book.

Comment: Your `.cls` file loads `biblatex`. With `biblatex` the bibliography is created semi-automatically. `thebibliography` is the fully manual way of creating bibliographies. The two approaches are incompatible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864, see also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: Do we close your question as a duplicate of the linked question, then?

Comment: My question shows explicitly the effect of using `biblatex` and the `thebibliography`environment at the same time on the command `\cite`, which is not given in the other post. If you think that this is not worth keeping my post online, then we can delete it definetly

Comment: Mhhh, I'd say the other post does exactly that as well. It has `\usepackage{biblatex}`, `thebibliography` and uses `\cite`. In fact the advantage of the other post over yours is that it has everything wrapped up in one document (and MWE) while there are only non-compilable snippets here. You should not delete your question, it remains searchable as a duplicate and can provide help for others that way. But I don't think your question needs a separate answer or needs to be kept open.

Comment: Okay I think you're right, thanks for your remark. Do you see a way how I could have found the other post out of my situation?

Comment: I think it would have been quite hard for you to find that post. Even knowing that the relevant bits to google for are `biblatex`, `thebibliography` and "bold" or "undefined" I didn't find the other question via google and the search function on this site is not really known to yield better results than google. I only found the other question because I knew I had written the answer not too long ago.