# When using the standard LaTex bibliography, \cite{key} isn't showing up as a number in the text

Tags: citing

I am using \cite{key} to cite sources in the text, but the name in the "key" part (which contains the author I am citing) is showing up in square brackets in my text instead of just as a number corresponding to the number in the bibliography. My bibliography is set up correctly, and numbers are on each item. I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing. 
I am using MikTex. I got my information for citing from chapter 9 of http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex/latex-intro.pdf

Here is a sample:

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}`

```
A new experiment has been proposed by MIT researchers in hopes to find information about the the axion. The interesting thing about this particular experiment is that it simulates a magnetar, which is a type of neutron star that generates an incredibly powerful magnetic field; the prototype of the experiment will be about the size of the palm of a hand.\cite{Chu} The experiment uses magnetic coils wound in a toroid, or donut, shape. The researchers claim that an axion in the presence of the magnetic field created by this simulated magnetar will cause the field to waver; this wavering would produce small oscillations at a frequency related to the mass of the axion.\cite{Chu} The experiment ultimately aims to identify the axion's size.\cite{Chu}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Chu}  Chu, Jennifer. "Team simulates a magnetar to seek dark matter particle." \textit{phys.org}. 7 October, 2016. \linebreak \indent https://phys.org/news/2016-10-team-simulates-magnetar-dark-particle.html\#nRlv
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: we cant help you if you will not provide small but complete document which produce your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864. You can't mix the manual way of creating bibliographies with `thebibliography` with the automatic way of creating bibliographies with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. For some reason, using `\usepackage{biblatex}` makes the `key` in `\cite{key}` appear instead of the numbers. Once `\usepackage{biblatex}` was removed, the problem went away.

Comment: With biblatex, you have to call a different program, please see https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Reading your question again, you should have a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies