# Why bibliography does not work on overleaf.com?

Tags: biblatex

I cannot get bibliography to work correctly on overleaf.com

Below a minimal case. The citation in the abstract instead of rendering as [1], renders as `[bib:imdb]`, and I get an error in the log file: `You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Try citation \cite{bib:imdb}
\end{abstract}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{bib:imdb} IMDB
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your using a manual bibliography while also loafing the biblatex package. Those does not mix. Either outcomment biblatex or replace the thebibliography with something appropriate for biblatex

Comment: `thebibliography` and the `biblatex` package are incompatible. You can *either* use `thebibliography` and retain full manual control over your bibliography output, *or* `biblatex` and get an automatic bibliography and citations. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864

Comment: Very good. Closed this question as a duplicate of the linked one.