# How to use \cite in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

So here's my problem: I am trying to use `\cite{}` in a `beamer`. I would like the output of `\cite{{AB_00}` to be either something like `[1]` or `Author A \& Author B`, which is essentially what I've written in brackets. Below is my code and its output:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme[hideothersubsections, right, width=22mm]{Goettingen}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test \cite{AB_00}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Author A \& Author B]{AB_00} A \& B 2000
\end{thebibliography}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Undesired output]

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I've tried turning my code into a m.w.e. If however something is unclear, please let me know so I can try clearing it up.

Comment: The manual way of creating bibliographies with `thebibliography` can not be used with  `biblatex` as it is completely incompatible with that package. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277567/35864

Comment: If you want to use `biblatex`, remove `thebibliography` and write a `.bib` file for your entries (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864). If you want to use a manual bibliography, just drop `biblatex` (remove the `\usepackage{biblatex}` in the MWE). See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber