# Can't cite bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I have a problem with Bibliography on my document.

At start I really had an issue printing it, now that  I found a way like this

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem {2003ApJ...596.1104V}...
```

My starting commands (before the documents start) are:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=190mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\usepackage{macros}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

But when I write

```
\cite{2003ApJ...596.1104V}
```

I only get

**2003ApJ...596.1104V**

I have see everything in google, and found that  I shouldnt use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

But when I remove it, It doesnt even compile the Bibliography.

Any advice? :(

Comment: You can't use `thebibliography` *and* `biblatex`: It is either or. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864

Comment: @moewe But if I remove biblatex, I get an unknown error. If I add it. BBgraphy shows up but citations don't work. Have tried creating .bib but does not even show up (have tried everything about it)

Comment: Note that your should load packages only once in your preamble (`graphicx`, `wrapfig`, `hyperref` are loaded multiple times). `hyperref` should normally be loaded last.

Comment: @moewe Fixed it. Doesn't fix this but yeah ty for tip :)

Comment: You haven't shown a full example document (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), but with your setup there should be no undefined control sequence if you don't load `biblatex`. But you need to remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) first.

Comment: You are mixing up different things. Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies for a quick overview.

Comment: @moewe True! Had to delete them all manually. Post it as an answer to upvote it if you want. really thanks!

Comment: @Johannes_B ty for te input! :)

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392637/35864 then. I'll edit the answer there and mention the temporary files.

Comment: I guess https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277567/35864 would be the better duplicate because it avoids the `tikz-feynman` red herring.